# Funções de callback são assíncronas, somente com métodos espcíficos como setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Verificando a app construída pelo Philip Roberts( http://latentflip.com/loupe ) que demonstra o funcionamento do event loop do browser e webapi, notei que somente quando utilizamos funções callbacks chamando métodos como setTimeout..., há manifestação da webapi para considerar esse chamada como assíncrona.

Como posso saber quais métodos são executados de forma assíncrona então?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quais os métodos que são executados de forma assíncrona?

Para além do `setTimeout` que referiste há o `setInterval`, chamadas `ajax`/`xhr`, `Promises`, `async`/`await` e todas as funções passadas a auscultadores de eventos.

Na prática, saber quais as funções assíncronas de forma geral é dificil, quem as escreve deve estar ciente de que as está a usar.

Mas pode dizer-se de modo geral que funções que esperam por algo acontecer são assíncronas. Seja um temporizador (`setTimeout`/`setInterval`), um ajax a um servidor externo, ou estando à espera de um evento que será acionado.